# Why am I unable to declare a variable inside a function with a nested function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to declare a var    `var origPage;` inside a function with a nested function (NOT the nested function, but the outside one), but for some reason it's not registering.

```
function noticeSearch() {

    var origPage = null;

    $(".srh-input").keyup(function(e) {
        var e = e || event;
        keycode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        var keyword = $(".srh-input").val();
        console.log(origPage);
        console.log(currentPage);
        if ((e.which == 8) && (keyword === "")) {
            currentPage = origPage;
        } else if (keyword === "") {
            tooltip(".srh-input", "请输入关键字查询");
            origPage = currentPage;
        } else {
            $(".srh-input").tooltip('destroy');
            currentPage = 1;
        }
        $("#srh-btn").trigger("click");

    });

    $("#srh-btn").on("click", function() {

        notice.findList();
    });
}
```

When I run it, it says that the variable origPage is undefined in my console. My `keyword === ""` always returns true at first so origPage should be set to whatever page I'm on but it's not.  I can't declare it in my keyup function because I don't want my variable to be reset to undefined after every key press. Am I not allowed to declare variables in wrapper functions?

EDIT: currentPage is already defined. Sorry for not mentioning beforehand.

I now have a new problem. Once I changed the value of origPage to null, none of my other code seems to run. I will try to solve this myself.

Comment: At what point are you checking the value of `origPage`?

Comment: I suppose your first `if` clause becomes active where you are assigning `origPage` _to_ `currentPage` and which is where it breaks since `origPage` has no default value to begin with?

Comment: does it tell you where this error occurred (line number for instance)

Comment: @JamesThorpe I just edited the code so now you can see. I am logging the value of origPage to my console after every keypress, but it is never changed from null. I know that my if statement `keyword === ""` is running because the tooltip shows, but my origPage value isn't changing. currentPage is a previously declared variable not show in the code and has a default value of 1.

Comment: Perhaps also log `currentPage` at the same time so you can be sure of it's value at this point, just to rule it out.

Comment: I think your `origPage` needs to reside outside of the function `noticeSearch` scope because it seems like you want the value to sustain throughout the lifecycle of your application.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I just checked it, and that also isn't showing up in my console...

Comment: Sounds like your problem is elsewhere then...

Comment: @JamesThorpe Haha, it seems so. Thank you for your help though. Everything runs fine if I get rid of the origPage variable, but once I declare it, no matter where I declare it, everything gets messed up.

Comment: Prepare a jsFiddle if you can, or show your HTML as well as complete JS if it is not too much to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem more comes down to problem logic

```
var currentPage = 1;

function noticeSearch() {

    var origPage = null;

    $(".srh-input").keyup(function (e) {
        var e = e || event;
        keycode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        var keyword = $(".srh-input").val();
console.log('orig page is : ' + origPage);

        if ((e.which == 8) && (keyword === "")) {
            currentPage = origPage;
            console.log('case 1');
        } else if (keyword === " ") {
            //tooltip(".srh-input", "请输入关键字查询");
            origPage = currentPage;
            console.log('orig page is set to: ' + origPage);
            console.log('case 2');
        } else {
            //$(".srh-input").tooltip('destroy');
            currentPage = 1;
            console.log('case 3');

        }
        $("#srh-btn").trigger("click");

    });

    $("#srh-btn").on("click", function () {

        notice.findList();
    });
}

noticeSearch();
```

Using this code I could get the value of `origPage` to log just fine. Just press space once to get into the first `else if`

https://jsfiddle.net/fzw8xv5b/3/

Your problem was this

```
if ((e.which == 8) && (keyword === "")) {
    currentPage = origPage;
} else if (keyword === "") {
    tooltip(".srh-input", "请输入关键字查询");
    origPage = currentPage;
```

That is checking whether the backspace button was pressed and the input is empty. Else check if the input is empty. This line is likely never being called as what causes the input to be empty on keyup except the backspace key?

Comment: When the code is first initialized, the input is empty. I understand what you are trying to say, but I'm also confused because my tooltip shows when I mouse over the input. However, I will try your code out and see if it works.

Comment: Yes but when the code is first initalized the `keyup` event is not fired so that code is never reached.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I see that your code runs, but for some reason I'm having trouble producing the same results even with the same code but that's an issue on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether currentPage was defined previously, it is lost within the scope of the function in which you declared it (unless you defined it on the window). When you set origPage = currentPage, you are assigning within a different scope than where you defined currentPage. Note that you are passing a callback to the keyup function which will not have the local scope you are assuming you are in. Making currentPage a global variable may resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: origPage is not known on your keyup function because it's an event handler and it's because of closures. Alternatively, you can pass the data it uses here.

function noticeSearch() {

```
var origPage = null;

$(".srh-input").on('keyup', {origPage: origPage}, function(e) {
    var e = e || event;
    keycode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var keyword = $(".srh-input").val();
    console.log(origPage);
    console.log(currentPage);
    if ((e.which == 8) && (keyword === "")) {
        currentPage = origPage;
    } else if (keyword === "") {
        tooltip(".srh-input", "请输入关键字查询");
        origPage = currentPage;
    } else {
        $(".srh-input").tooltip('destroy');
        currentPage = 1;
    }
    $("#srh-btn").trigger("click");

});

$("#srh-btn").on("click", function() {

    notice.findList();
});
```

}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Put the declaration outside the `noticeSearch()` and make it global:

```
var origPage = null;
function noticeSearch() {
    //....
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it will work for sure.

Comment: @JamesThorpe what do you mean with "suitable"? It doesn't work!

Comment: Indeed, but not because of where this particular variable is declared.  Looks like it's do to with `currentPage` from the discussion in the comments.

Comment: @SmartDev I have tested it, and there were no changes. Thank you for the input though.

Comment: `origPage` is defined in a suitable scope for it's use in the OP's code.  Moving it outside of the `noticeSearch` function won't make any difference.  Hence a downvote - "this answer is not useful", simply because it won't make any difference.  And indeed didn't, according to @khorik.